# Не запускается программа на СИ, ошибок нет

Tags: c, указатели, ос

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int *arr;
    arr[0] = 2;
    arr[1] = 3;
    printf("%d, %d", *arr, *(arr + 1));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Код нормально запускается и работает с помощью онлайн IDE (repl.it, там код на СИ запускается из под OS Linux), но на моём компьютере (Windows 10) происходит что-то непонятное. При компиляции (`gcc main.c -o main`) никаких ошибок не возникает, но программа в результате ничего не делает. Открывается пустая консоль на 1-2 секунды и исчезает.

Если же при инициализации указателя на массив присвоить ему результат выполнения функции `malloc`, то всё будет работать нормально.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int *arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    ...
}
```

Действительно ли это связано с операционными системами? Где можно почитать про поведение программы в этом случае?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё правильно. Неинициализированная переменная имеет произвольное значение. Если эта переменная - указатель, то он указывает в случайную область памяти. Поптыка записать в случайную область памяти числа 2, закономерно приводит к [ошибке сегментации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), и ваша программа падает.

Comment: Но [тут](https://repl.it/@don2quixote/FoolishHideousYottabyte) работает! Почему?

Comment: Скажите, когда вы переходите дорогу в неположенном месте и остаетесь живы - вас это удивляет или нет? :) Вы нарушаете правила, но это же не означает, что вас тут же надо убивать. Так бывает и с программами :)

Comment: @Harry Именно этой мыслью я и руководствовался, пока кликал 1000 раз на кнопку `run`, пока не выдаст ошибку)